# How make file_name displaying instead of <media 1>? Relationships Flask-admin

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

[media is displaying like list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guiJu.png)

How to display file_name instead of list instance?
i got this relationship

```
class wards(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "wards"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    about = db.Column(db.Text(300))
    aim = db.Column(db.Text(300))
    geo_point_x = db.Column(db.Float)
    geo_point_y = db.Column(db.Float)
    fixed_summa = db.Column(db.Boolean(1))
    summa = db.Column(db.Integer)
    type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    images = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable = True, default='default.jpg')
    media = db.relationship('media')

    pass

class media(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    ward_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('wards.id'))
    file_name = db.Column(db.String())
    pass
```

this is edit_form function that calls while editing

```
    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        form = super(ViewWards,self).edit_form(obj)
        for item in form.data["media"]:
            print(item.file_name)
        return form
```

I can get file_name in terminal, but how to get it in browser?

Im new on stackoverflow.

I've tried to override edit_form, but cant find solution. There is lack of examples on flask-admin, and documentation is very confusing.

Comment: @pjcunningham, im not sure what i need to do with __rerp__  and  __str__, form_extra_fields accept only class so i cant load methods in it. I need to return file_name instead of <media 1> thing. I read that edit_form is sending form wich include media list, so i tried to override it but no effect. Sorry im new in flask-admin so i not quite understand how it works.

Comment: In your `Media` class you need to define a `__str__` method which returns the human readable form of instances of the class `Media`. In Flask-Admin the underlying form widget for the relationship will use the `__str__` method for display purposes. In your situation `__str__` method should return `self.file_name`.